# Sharepoint 2016: Format hyperlinks in a column

Tags: 2016, hyperlink, client-side-rendering, formatting

How can I format the hyperlinks of a specific column. In my case I have a list with several columns and one of them with title "Quicklink" is formatted as "Hyperlink" and displays a standard link to another URL. The hyperlink itself is displayed not very prominent, which is why I want to change the format of it to be displayed in bold and maybe a bigger font size.

How to address this specific column to display the links in bold and bigger font size?

Thanks for your consideration and support!

Comment: You can use the client side rendering in SharePoint for such requirements: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views

Comment: Looking for a code snippet, preferable CSS as I am a bit used to these, hope thats possible as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this CSS a try:

```
table.ms-listviewtable a:link, table.ms-listviewtable a:visited, table.ms-summarystandardbody a:link, table.ms-summarystandardbody a:visited, tr.ms-itmhover a:link, tr.ms-itmhover a:visited {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Willman, this does exactly what I wanted! Awesome, have a great day!